# Can I clone my existing Ubuntu 12.10 and install to USB

Tags: 12.10, clone

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed from scratch. It is set up the way I would want to have it also for my Laptop and work Laptop.

But rather than actually installing the OS again two more times, I want to be able to clone my OS onto a Usb drive and run it off that rather than the computer hard disk.

How can I do this?

Regards
-Kyle.

Comment: Have you tried Gparted? You can just copy/paste partitions from one place to another. (Literally copy/paste)

Answer (score 1):

**Remastersys** is a tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Debian,  Ubuntu or derivative installation.

1) It can make a **full system backup** including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install.

2) It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends.  This will **not** have any of your personal user data in it.

[Remastersys Webpage](http://www.remastersys.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could back up your `\HOME` directory, and then copy and paste it. Then get rid of your other `\HOME` directory.

Hope this helps!!!